# How to properly clean the ventilation slots on my Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I moved to a tropical country and have a real problem with mosquitos and like insects

[image].

They house themselves (dying) in the ventilation slots and I regularly clean it up with a cotton swab, but the space is so small that the slots stay dirty and I'm worried the MBP will have problems, also I like to have my things neat.

What would be the best way to clean this part of my computer, without pushing the mosquitos and the squished entrails deeper into the vents?

Answer (score 5):

Properly?

Head over to [ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/) and look for your model.

Open up the bottom case, disassemble the fans. That is unscrew typically 3 screws and disconnect the cables.

Then hold on to the rotors so that they don't start spinning.

Then use a can of *compressed air* to blow away the biggest chunks of debris. *Out of* the fan-assembly, and *out of* the grills that would to the outside.

Afterwards use a damp cloth or better yet alcohol on a q-tip or similar implement to remove the finer and more sticky residues.

Let any fluids evaporate.
Then re-assemble everything.

The screwing part is easy, the cables need somewhat more delicate handling, so be careful.

Do not use a vacuum and do not let the rotors spin while cleaning!
Static electricity buildup or damage to the motors may result.

Related info:
[How to deal with a loud MacBook fan. Here are some noisy fan fixes.](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-deal-with-a-loud-macbook-fan/)
[How to Clean Out Dust From Your MacBook or iMac](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/clean-dust-macbook-imac/)
[Cleaning fans, grille out of MBP](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3197958)

Comment: Why is it necessary not to let the rotors spin?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly the simplest answer is the best, get an adapter for your vacuum cleaner that is designed to get into small spaces.

I pretty much did an internet search on that and [this is](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SSNPBK) one of the first things that came up. So I've never used this particular product, it is an example, only you can determine its suitability.

I've often made adapters myself out of pop bottles, corks, duct tape and straws but they tend to reflect the skill of the maker and what parts I had on hand at the time (so not great).

Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.